# Unable to install cafee with opencv-3.2.0-dev

Tags: c++, opencv, installation, caffe, pycaffe

I have followed all the instructions given [here](http://hanzratech.in/2015/07/27/installing-caffe-on-ubuntu.html), but when I

```
import caffe,
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have even appended `LIBRARIES` with `opencv_imgcodecs` in the `MakeFile`

Opencv version : `3.2.0-dev`
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

How do I resolve this error ?

Comment: I had a similar error recently, although I got down to missing core.hpp -- which is opencv2.  I suspect a version inconsistency, but I'm still researching.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to have two versions of opencv installed, the version of opencv which works with caffe ?

Comment: have you compiled caffe with `OPENCV_VERSION := 3` in the `Makefile.config`?

Comment: Yes, I have done  `OPENCV_VERSION := 3`. I also get the error when I run the following command: `make runtest`:   

`.build_release/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [runtest] Error 127`

Comment: would you mind adding the code of your Makefile.config and Makefile,do you have this line INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ /usr/include/opencv in your Makefile.config? what about this  ifeq ($(OPENCV_VERSION), 3)
                 LIBRARIES += opencv_imgcodecs in your Makefile? if you have all of them enabled then you didnt built opencv with opencv_contrib, here is a good guidance how to build opencv http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/,i d suggest to build opencv3.1.0  because it worked for me

Comment: for no other specific reason and 3.2.0 didnt work ,after installing those ,you have to rebuild caffe again by deleting the build folder and restart the whole process,it took me two weeks to get it going,so i know a fair amount about it